# Changing Excel spreadsheet cells through the usage of Jenkins

Tags: excel, vba, jenkins, automation, parameterized

I want to make an adjustment to a cell in excel without opening the application for it. I want to do this with Jenkins so i can automate (regression)tests. (Is this even possible??)

As you can see in the image I attached, I wat to change a “N” value in excel to an “Y” value, or vice versa. I want to achieve this trough the UI of Jenkins. I’ve heard something like a parametrized build, but I can’t get my hands on any website or something that can tell me more about this subject.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

1. Open Jenkins
2. Select job
3. In that job select “Testdata A (Or the unique number 1)
4. Also select “Testdata A1” +” Testdata A2” (Or the unique number 1.1 & 1.2)
5. Save
6. Run Job
7. Jenkins takes my selection, opens excel in background and makes the modifications In excel by the selection I made true the UI of Jenkins.
8. In other words: by selecting “Testdata A” in Jenkins and running the job, the “N” in cel C2 needs to change to a “Y”. Also for other selections like the ones in cel C3 & C4
9. I want to do this for more then 1x. The idea is to use excel where all cell's already have a "N" and only changes to an "Y" when i select this true Jenkins.

My apologies for my bad English. I hope I have clearly described what I want. Please add a comment if you require more explanation. Thanks in advance

[Excel Testdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAOHi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it simpler to have Jenkins execute a `vbscript` that accesses and updates your file as required.  You can pass the relevant parameters to a script that will then do something along the lines of:

```
Dim xlApp : Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wkBk : Set wkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("pathToWorkBookHere")
Dim wSheet : Set wSheet = wkBk.WorkSheets("yourSheetNameHere")

With wSheet.Range("C3")
    .Value = Wscript.Arguments(0) ' This could be a Y or an N, whatever you passed into the script
End With
```

You could easily scale that up over multiple workbooks/worksheets/cells as required.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your suggestion. But does this mean i constantly need to change my VBscript to update my file? Because that's something i want to avoid.

Comment: No, you can pass parameters into the script in the execution line in the Jenkins job setup (steps 3&4 on your original list).  They are referenced in the script using `Wscript.Arguments(parameter number, indexed from 0)`.  You can write the code as generically as you need and parameterise anything you want to pass in like workbook name, path, sheet name, whatever you like.

Comment: So if i'm not mistaken, i need to constantly change my parameters CODE in Jenkins execution line in onder to achive what i want. 

I need to do this maybe 20-30x a day. And the cell selection can vary crom c1 till c25. isn't it time consuming if i have to do that over and over again. because that is something i want to avoid. i want to win time by doing it this way

Comment: Well maybe you can put the code for each update type into the script and then just schedule the job in Jenkins.  Since you haven't defined the rules on why certain cells will be updated I can't make a suggestion there.

Comment: thank you. Can you lend me a hand with 1 last thing? Whenever i attach a string paramater to it. Name: Test,  Default Value: Y and descripton: empty. Cell C3 gets filled out with the name "Test" instead of the value "Y". What am i doing wrong here? Where do i need to write my code parameter in Jenkins in order to get the "Y" instead of the "Tests". I execute my VBscipt through "Execute windows batch command" with the command: "call C:\locatin\to\path test" Note the final "test" in my command to attacht the parameter to it.

Comment: It seems like you're passing the "Test" string into the script as the argument rather than passing it as a Jenkins variable?  That would explain why you are getting the string rather than the value.  Try: `"call C:\location\to\path.vbs" test` so that Jenkins interprets the variable rather than the vbscript seeing it as a string

Comment: Thanks dave. your help was wonderfull. i needed to add % to test. so it was like **C:\location\to\path.vbs %test%**

Comment: Do you happen to have a solution for the following: I want to select through Jenkins the cells in Excel i want to make an "Y" or "N". So something like a dropdown in jenkins where i can choose for cell C3: Y, C4: Y C9: Y C10: N, C11:N, etcetra. do you think that's posibble? with or without vbscript?

Comment: Don't know how you could set it up in Jenkins tbh, but you could pass the string "C3:Y,C4:Y,C9:Y,C10:N,C11:N" in as the argument to the vb script.  Split this into an array using the ',' as delimiter and you have all the items to set.  For each item in this array, split it on the colon and use the first element as the range to set and the second element as the value to set.  You'd have to change the value of the string for every run though.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Is this called a "Named argument"?