# Jenkins building Excel by VBScript and Parameterized build

Tags: excel, vba, jenkins, vbscript, parameters

[Changing Excel spreadsheet cells through the usage of Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326446/changing-excel-spreadsheet-cells-through-the-usage-of-jenkins)

My seek in help is based on the link above. I've been working on this for like 3 months, but still can't find a solution to it. I hope someone can help me out.

I want to achive the following:

1. Get a specific excel sheet cell filled in by a value. In my case the letter “Y” (See image 1) [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe07H.jpg)
2. Get the excel sheet cell filled with the letter "Y" through the selection from the Jenkins user interface(Parameterized build) (See image 2) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvBFG.jpg)
3. Get the letter "Y" be filled in a specfific cell inside the Excel Sheet. So when i select "Input for cell c3 as seen in image 2, i want to make sure that the letter "Y" gets excatlly filled inside Cell C3 in Excel and not other cells aswell.

So basically when I select “Testdata A” as Head and “Input for cel C3” as Sub,  I want the value “Y” to be written inside cell C3 inside Excel. 
Currently I managed to get the letter “Y” behind the names “input for cel C3”. I do this with the code:

```
if (Head.equals("Testdata A")) {
  return ['Y':'Input for cel C3', 'N':'Input for cel C4', 'S': 'Input for cel C9', 'A':'Input for cel C10']
}
```

In my VBSCript I use a code to get the excel be filled by the value I select through Jenkins, but this code simply indicated that the cells C3, c4 and C5 all needs to get filled with 1 given argument.So even if i select "input for c3", all other cells will also get filled. The code is:

```
Dim xlApp
Dim wkBk
Dim wSheet
Dim y
Dim n

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.visible = True 
Set wkBk =  xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\location\of\excelFile\Excel.xlsb")
Set wSheet = wkBk.WorkSheets("Sheetname")

wSheet.Range("C3").Value =  Wscript.Arguments(0) 
wSheet.Range("C4").Value = Wscript.Arguments(0)
wSheet.Range("C5").Value = Wscript.Arguments(0)

wkBk.Save
```

I call my vbscript with the parameter argument as followed:

```
call D:\location\to\script\.vbs %Sub%
```

Guys/girls, help me out, How can i manage to fill a specific cell through a selection from Jenkins.

Comment: Are you returning the following as a string? `'Y':'Input for cel C3', 'N':'Input for cel C4', 'S': 'Input for cel C9', 'A':'Input for cel C10'`

Comment: Yes, The selection "input for cel C3", Gives me a string "Y", aswell as for the others

Comment: My answer below will work if the argument you pass into the string reads `'Y':'Input for cel C3', 'N':'Input for cel C4', 'S': 'Input for cel C9', 'A':'Input for cel C10'`; if that's not the case I'll need to edit it?

Comment: I think im leading you to the wrong way with my odd description.  The letters "N" , "S"  etc are wrong because they need to be unique. I cant somehow use 4x "Y" in this script

Comment: Basically they all need to print the letter "Y".  All i want is for when i select 1 of the 4 options (the 'input for cell ..."  ) to give me a "Y" as output, and place that in the cell that matches the cells inside excel. So when i select "input for c3" it prints me out a "Y" string, which then that needs to get placed inside cell c3 in excel. When i select input for cell c5, and thus not select input for C4,  cell c4 needs to be skipped, and the input given by "input for cell c5" needs to be palced in cell C5 inside excel,

Comment: When i select "Input for cell c3" & "Input for cell 5", i want the letter "Y" to be only filled inside C3 & C5 within Excel.

Comment: If it's just setting a Y in whatever cell you pass in, then just pass the cell value to the vbscript and let it Set the "Y" for you.  I'll edit my answer a bit so you can see what I'm meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code above, it seems you need to split the input variable and iterate over it like this:

```
Dim xlApp
Dim wkBk
Dim wSheet
Dim iLoop, setVal, setCell, myArguments, tempArray

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.visible = True 
Set wkBk =  xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\location\of\excelFile\Excel.xlsb")
Set wSheet = wkBk.WorkSheets("Sheetname")
myArguments = Split(Wscript.Arguments(0), ",") ' myArguments is now an array of the cells to be updated
For iLoop = 0 to UBound(myArguments)
    wSheet.Range(myArguments(iLoop)).Value = "Y" 
Next
wkBk.Save
```

Edit 1 : If you are always setting a "Y", then just pass in the Cells you want updated as a comma separated string e.g. `"C1,C3,C5"`.  The code above will set a Y in each of the cells passed into the script and not any others.

Comment: Thanks Dave, Youre my Hero